# Is there a way to make the keys of a class iterable?

Tags: python, class

I'm need to read different datasets, and all of them have some equal properties (e.g. ID and name) and some unique properties. I know that I can build a different function to read each dataset, but I was wondering if it is possible to build a generic dataset reader if I use something like this

My class:

```
def MyClass():
  def __init(self):
    self.default_prop1 = ''
    self.default_prop2 = ''
```

My main file:

```
def main():
  keys = ['default_prop1', 'default_prop2', 'not_default_prop1', 'not_default_prop2' ]

  obj_myclass = MyClass()

  for i in keys:
    #Here
    obj_myclass[i] = file.readline()
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: In general if you need something like this you should just have a single attribute containing a list or dictionary.

Comment: You can use `getattr()` to access attributes dynamically. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought about getattr, but I need to 'create' custom atributes to the class, getattr only allow me to view the data dinamically. I also thought about the dictionary, but this solution has it's own problems. A class that only has a dictionary, is a little bit weird (at this point, i can use an array of dictionaries, instead of an array of classes to represent the dataset). But from what I have found, I think that this is the way.

Comment: `setattr()` lets you create them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vars()` mechanism. Fixing two typos in your sample code, to give

```
class MyClass():                           # not def
      def __init__(self):                  # not __init
        self.default_prop1 = ''
        self.default_prop2 = ''
```

you can do

```
>>> mc = MyClass()
>>> vars(mc)
{'default_prop1': '', 'default_prop2': ''}
```

The object returned by `vars()` is a proper `dict` (it returns the `__dict__` attribute) and can be updated the way you want.

```
>>> vars(mc)["new_prop"] = "Fred"
>>> mc.new_prop
'Fred'
```

Or, if you want to do it in a loop:

```
>>> for i in (v := vars(mc)):
        v[i] = file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll update your class a little bit:

```
def Car(): #an example of a car class
  def __init(self, props):
    self.props = ({}, {})
```

Now you can iterate over the default properties and the extra ones:

```
def main() 
  new_car = Car(({"year": 1998}, {"sports_car_type": "countach"}))
  # Now, you can go through the keys in both dictionaries of this new object
  print("defaults:")
  for key, val in new_car.props[0].items():
    print(key, val)
  print("~~~~~~~~~\extras:")
  for key, val in new_car.props[1].items():
    print(key, val)

main()
```